# Eclipse: How to create two different key bindings for different contexts in plugin.xml?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create two key bindings for different dsls with different context but the issue which I am facing is that if the key binding does not belong to first dsl but still it is visible there.

First key binding is [image]

Second key binding is [image]

First key binding belongs to .conv xtext file and Second key binding belongs to .test xtext file.

So, how can I hide the first key binding if the .test xtext editor is opened and vice versa?

I have created two different contexts for both but still both the key bindings appears on any XTEXT editor when I press ctrl+shift+A .

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well have you set the `contextId` in the key binding? Show us the bindings.

Comment: I have added the images how I added key binding and context.

The same way I added other binding and context for different dsl in another ui plugin.

Comment: You will need to use a different context id for each editor. Show us the full set up for all the editors - and please don't use images, just plain text of the plugin.xml contents.

Comment: I added different context id for another editor.
But in our code, we have a class called DSLEditor where we are activating context.

final IContextService contextService = site.getService(IContextService.class);
contextService.activateContext("project.ui.editorcontext");
contextService.activateContext("conv.ui.editorcontext");

Comment: Like I said each editor has to use a different context id if you want different bindings.